# Socket Programming - Server content written to Client (write())

Tags: c, sockets, server, client

I am writing a file navigator, that connects a client to a server and lets the user list all the files in the current directory of the server (the server location).

Suppose the directory contains the following files:

```
test.txt
Makefile
server.c
```

Now, I want the user (on client side) to be able to get a list of all the files/foldes on the server end.

I have already written a WORKING piece of code that displays all files, but only on the SERVER side. It looks as follows:

```
void print_content(int socket_num) {
    struct dirent *entry;   //Entry
    DIR *dir_stream;    //Directory stream
    dir_stream = opendir("./"); //Open current directory
    if(dir_stream != NULL) {
        while((entry = readdir(dir_stream))) {
            printf("%s\n", entry->d_name); //Gets name
            write(socket_num, entry->d_name, 1024); //WRITE?
        }
        (void) closedir(dir_stream);
    }
    else {
        error("Problems with directory");
    }
}
```

As mentioned, this prints out correctly on the SERVER side.

However, is there a way to easily send these strings to the CLIENT, instead of using the write() function?

In other words, is there a function more similar to printf() than write(), that writes to a client?

Comment: I think you're a bit ahead of yourself. Before you figure out how to get the data into the right form to send to the client, you have to decide what that form is. Have a look at the [specification for FTP](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) for an idea of how to do this.

Comment: You mean like sprintf followed by write? But I do agree with @DavidSchwartz, you may want to look at how people already solved that problem.

Comment: There is no _easy_ way to do this, but indeed, there is a way to do this. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @SergeyA I get a string with the file name (entry->d_name). Is there a way to send each of these strings to the client? 
Ideally using something similar to: write(socket_number, entry->d_name, size).

Comment: @northerner, close to that, but you'd also need to prefix your string with it's size. On the receiver side, you'd have to first read the string size from the socket, and than keep reading until the whole string is read (there is no guarantee you will get the whole string with a single attempt). I also suggest to use `send` and `recv` instead of `read` and `write` - they are much more clear in this sense and have additional flags. And since you will be sending multiple strings, you should prefix the whole thing with the number of the strings. (I assume we are doing tcp here).

Comment: @northerner There are two things you need to do: 1) Decide on the protocol. 2) Implement the protocol. You are asking us implementation questions when you haven't designed a protocol yet. You have a byte stream between the server and the client. You have to decide what bytes you want to push onto that byte stream. Then you can write code to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other words, is there a function more similar to printf() than write(), that writes to a client?

Yes, there's `fprintf()`, which you can use for the purpose if you first `fdopen()` a stream (*i.e.* a `FILE *`) around your connected socket's file descriptor.  You would be well advised to `fflush()` after all the `fprintf()`s to be sure the last bits are sent without delay, and definitely before discarding the stream.

HOWEVER, you probably don't want to do that.  [`f`]`printf()` is for *formatting* data; sending it to a chosen destination is a secondary, albeit important, consideration.  Unless the client you describe is exceedingly thin, you probably want the client, not the server, to perform formatting.  In that case, what you need to do is serialize [the needed parts of] a `struct dirent`, and send *those* to the client, for it to use as it pleases.  If you just pass formatted data over the socket, then there's not much the client can do other than slurp up all the incoming data and spit it out as-is in the UI.  Only and forever.  That's more or less what I mean by "exceedingly thin".

Additionally, if you do create a stream, be aware that when you close it, you will close the underlying socket, too.  If you discard it without closing it, on the other hand, then that will constitute a resource leak.